# How should map these data coming from Axios Http request (w/ React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I've made an async call using redux-thunk and Axios. Everything is working fine however I have hard time building my component. I don't know how to map my props/data. Here is how the data are stored in my store :

[image]

I want to access the second data Array. I'm trying this :

```
            const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
            return {
                isFetching: state.ThunkData.isFetching,
                data: state.ThunkData.data.data,
                error: state.ThunkData.error,
            };
        };
```

with the following error : `Cannot read property 'data' of null`. I need to replace `data: state.ThunkData.data.data` by `data: state.ThunkData.data` to make my app work.

Also adding `{console.log(this.props.data.data)}` in my component return me this :

[image]

How can I pass the data I want into my props so I can do something like this :

```
                        <ul>
          { props.map((m, i) =>
            <li key={i}>{m.authorname}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
```

If needed here is my detailed code :

**My action creator :**

```
export const fetchTest = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null
  });
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/authors')
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching:false,
            data: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
            ype: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
      });
      console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });
};
```

**My component :**

```
class asyncL extends React.Component {
                      constructor(props) {
                        super(props);
                      }
                      componentWillMount() {
                      this.props.fetchTest(this.props.thunkData)
                      }
                      render() {
                      if (this.props.isFetching) {
                            return <p>{console.log(this.props.isFetching)}</p>
                      }else if (this.props.error) {
                      return <div>ERROR {this.props.error}</div>
                      }else {
                      return <p>{console.log(this.props.data.data)}</p> 
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

**My reducer :**

```
const initialState = {data:null,isFetching: false,error:null};
export const ThunkData = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST':
        case 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE':
        return { ...state, isFetching: action.isFetching, error: action.error };

        case 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {data: action.data, isFetching: action.isFetching,
                 error: null });
        default:return state;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've the solution :

I update my action creator to this ( add the response item) :

```
export const fetchTest = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
        isFetching:true,
        error:null
  });
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/authors')
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
            isFetching:false,
            data: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
            ype: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILURE',
            isFetching:false,
            error:err
      });
      console.error("Failure: ", err);
    });
};
```

that is solving my multiple object level request.
and now updating my component is easy :

```
class authorL extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    var props = this.props.author;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        { props.map((m, i) =>
          <li key={i} onClick={() => this.props.getFilteredName(m.name)}>
            {m.name}
          </li>
        )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```